# Permission Issue while getting node Ref using dbid

Tags: alfresco-webscripts

I am facing the issue while using

```
NodeRef nodeRef=nodeService.getNodeRef(longNodeRef);
```

This function to get the node Refrence using dbid.  i am passing admin alf_ticket its giving this exception

```
You do not have the appropriate permissions to perform this operation.
```

can anyone help me what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time i got the solution

```
 NodeRef noderef= (NodeRef) AuthenticationUtil.runAsSystem(new AuthenticationUtil.RunAsWork<Object>() { 
              public Object doWork() throws Exception {
                  NodeRef refNode=nodeService.getNodeRef(longNodeRef);
               return refNode;
              }
            });
```

it's working fine for me.